# Bash/Sed how to insert a string with special characters into a file

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a script that I'm currently working on. And I've run into an issue where I need to prompt a user to enter a string, then encrypt that with sha-512, and then insert it into a specific file

So far I have:

```
pass= grub-crypt --sha512
```

Which returns the hashed value I need. However, I'm running into the issue where sed will read the special characters from the hash.

I then tried:

```
sed -i.bak "20i$pass" /foo/bar
```

But that doesn't work. I assume it's still reading the special characters when it substitutes the variable for the characters in the string. So I wanted to try and add an escape character before every character in the string like this:

```
sed 's:\(.\{1\\}\)\1:g'
```

However, this isn't working for me either. I'm new to sed, so any explanation would be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: It might help if you posted some example values of `$pass` for which you're having problems, the exact commands that you're using, and the results that you're getting.

Comment: If you want to capture the output of grub-crypt, you need something like `pass=$(grub-crypt --sha512)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases where special characters such as `* . / $` abound in text it's easiest not to use insert the text directly. The alternative is to add backslashes which is a drab manual solution.

Rather use the `r` sed function - which reads in the following file at the address specified (in this case line 20). Note there is no error handling in this code:

```
grub-crypt --sha512 > hash.tmp
sed -i.bak '20r hash.tmp /foo/bar      
rm hash.tmp
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work, either. I think it is still reading the special characters in the hash.

Comment: updated answer - works for me with special chars like `$5ks&-£££%()-$`.

Comment: @suspectus: I think the second variant in your first version of the answer should work. Did you really mean to post a revision in which `$pass` is ***not quoted at all***?

Comment: @G-Man agreed - the variable needs to be quoted. I don't know what I was thinking of.

Comment: So an example of the special characters in the has are '$', '.', and '/'. Otherwise. running the following script commands 

`#!/bin/bash
pass= grub-crypt ---sha-512  
sed -i.bak '20i\  
'$pass'' /foo/bar`

It then prints the hash of the password that I enter, and inserts two blank lines(at line 20) in the file that I'm trying to insert the hash too

Comment: I tried it with `sed -i.bak "20i\\
$pass" /foo/bar` and received the same result. I was thinking, would I be better off trying to read through each character in the variable, and add a backslash to escape each one?

Comment: Forget trying to get `i` function to work for your problem - it's too much pain. Try `r` instead (see updated answer).

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much. So I'm assuming that if you're working with special characters such as this situation, you generally just want to move it to a temp file, and work from there?

Comment: Oh good! Correct - use a temp file when you can. It avoids all the meta-character expansion by the shell.